# How to make TextViews in a ListView to blink simultaneously

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-view

I have a ListView containing TextViews in its rows. On some rows, I would like the TextView to blink together, I mean turn on/off at the same time.
Any ideas how to sync them?

My app is Android 8 API compatible, so ObjectAnimator is not an option for me.

With my current implementation I get a bizarre behavior - not only the text views blinks are not synchronized, but when I scroll I sometimes see a TextView flashes quickly a few times, like the Animation runs on FF and then stabilized on the normal rate.

Here is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowt, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListRowUID data = (PollsListRowUID) getItem(position);
    if (data != null) {
        holder.dateTextView.setText(data.Date); 
        if (data.Date.equals(holder.inProgressText)) // turn the animation on/off
            holder.dateTextView.setAnimation(holder.blink);
        else 
            holder.dateTextView.setAnimation(null);
        holder.favoritesTextView.setText("" + data.FavoritesNum);
        holder.favoritesImageView.setImageResource(data.MarkedAsFavorite ? R.drawable.favorite_full_small : R.drawable.favorite_empty_small);
    } 
    return (convertView);
}

private class Holder {


    public Holder(View convertView) {
        dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        inProgressText = convertView.getResources().getString(R.string.in_progress); 
        favoritesTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoritesTextView);
        favoritesImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoritesImageView);


        blink = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        blink.setDuration(500); 
        blink.setStartOffset(20);
        blink.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        blink.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);


    }

    TextView dateTextView;
    TextView favoritesTextView;
    ImageView favoritesImageView;

    String inProgressText;
    Animation blink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to make your TextView blink

```
private void blink(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in milissegunds
        try{Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch (Exception e) {}
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usage);
                    if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    blink();
                }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) I'd like to use the fade-in/fade-out animation. 2) The thread is redundant - you could achieve that with handler.postDelayed and save you from creating list-longnumber of threads.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is small enough, you can consider using a vertical `LinearLayout` and adding your views to it.

This is a simple way to keep your animations synchronized.